# How to fix Not implemented error..(this code will be throw the error)

Tags: android, cloudinary

It's my code:

```
try {
    System.out.println("Cloudinaryyyy 0000  :");
    Map result = cloudinary.api().resources(ObjectUtils.asMap("resource_type","raw"));
    System.out.println("Cloudinaryyyy  :"+result);
}
catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d("DownloadManager", "Error:" + e);
}
catch (NetworkOnMainThreadException e) {
    System.out.println("Error 3" + e);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Error 3" + e);
}
```

In the cloudinary it throws the exception.

Comment: please elaborate your question wisely.

Comment: what do u mean...?

Comment: your questions is not really clear. It may not really helps the community to answer your question.

Comment: try to give the question clearly please. your question should include 1.your idea 2. your code example 3. where you going wrong. With these criteria we can give you some help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to configure the Cloudinary object?

```
Map config = new HashMap();
config.put("cloud_name", "n07t21i7");
config.put("api_key", "123456789012345");
config.put("api_secret", "abcdeghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz12");
Cloudinary cloudinary = new Cloudinary(config);
```

Also, you can try to run the sample projects on https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_java